# How to write inline lambda expression for a specific signature

Tags: c#, lambda

This is making my brain melt. Given these signatures of `IApplicationBuilder` how do I write a lambda expression that satisfies the extension method?

```
public IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
```

Extension method: (I want to satisfy this extension)

```
public static IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> middleware)
```

This is what I have now:

```
app.Map("/home/abc", config =>
    {
        config.Use(async (context, next) => // this matches Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>
        {
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see how that would match `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`. Such a lambda would have only one parameter, and you have two. What is the problem you are seeing? Is it an error? Are you sure you're not just missing a `using` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expression is actually correct. Looks like this is some sort of Roslyn/intellisense bug in VS2015 RC. If there are any unresolved references or anything that reports as a red squiggle inside of a lambda expression VS goes bonkers and reports variables of a type they are not.

I'm wondering if this exists in previous versions of VS and I just never ran into it..

[image]